# Unity blurry text

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to fix blurry text in unity? I know everyone and their grandmothers have asked this by now. I've tried TextMeshPro, I've tried downloading custom fonts. The text looks good in the scene view, but it looks crappy in the game view.

The text in game view https://i.stack.imgur.com/83o7J.png

The text in scene view https://i.stack.imgur.com/19sEM.png

Comment: Is that not antialiasing?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Unity will try to anti-alias that if OP uses an AA filter, but generally it's a resolution problem. TMP presents text as a slice of a sprite so if the sprite is low res this will happen. Best fix is to up the res.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that in the game view, the scale is set 1x.  Took me forever to figure out.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

When you import the font and create an atlas in TextMeshPro use the maximum atlas size (I believe that's 2048 x 2048) and use the slowest generation method (called 'Optimum').

As DiplomacyNotWar mentions, any AA solution you use (e.g. in the PostProcessing package) will reduce the aliasing a bit.